# AS3 - evaluating at runtime - D.eval vs hurlant

Tags: actionscript-3, eval

I need to pass in a string that gets evaluated at runtime.  So I can write this:

```
var foo =  someEvalMethod ( "dataObject.someValue" )
```

instead of:

```
if ( argIn == "dataObject.someValue")
   var foo = dataObject.someValue
}
```

Does anyone have an opinion on the following evaluate libraries, or better ones for AS3?  Thanks:

AS3 eval by hurlant:

http://eval.hurlant.com/

D.eval by RIA 1:

http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/

Comment: If all you need is access to properties and objects you don't necessarily need to complicate things with eval. Can you be a bit more specific about what you need and don't need?

Comment: Ahh shucks... D.eval's site is down :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know **AS3 eval** by hurlant is a "real" compiler. It parses code, generates bytecode and injects it to the Flash Player instance in use (through loadBytes() I guess).

**D.eval** has the same purpose but it does not generate bytecode, it parses expressions and execute them dynamically through its own API.

I see **D.eval as a good candidate** for what you are trying to achieve. It's not a full featured compiler, but it has enough APIs that cover many simple operations. Other than that it is a product that has a company behind, which is always a good guaranty.

Cheers!