# Inject AS3 or ABC to a swf file in runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, code-injection

I've been seeing some tools for a browsergame that injects code to a swf file in order to automate some parts of the game.

I've been reading about swf flash format and I'm still don't knowing how that's possible, maybe the program runs the swf file with a custom flash player?

If you could guide me in this I would be very appreciated, this is very interesting.

Comment: Just curious, can you post a link to the example(s) of this?

Comment: And have you looked into and AS3 libraries for executing AS3, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971856/as3-evaluating-at-runtime-d-eval-vs-hurlant

Comment: @Aaron http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/showthread.php?t=3588799 this tool injects the ai to the game client

Answer (score 0):

Just a try:

```
var actionString:String = "methodAddOne";
var paramString:String = "1";

function methodAddOne(num:String):void{
    trace(Number(num)+1);
}

this[actionString](paramString); //trace: 2
```

For a queue of params:

```
var actionString2:String="methodAdd";
var paramString2:String="1,2,3,-6";

function methodAdd(nums:String):void{
    var params:Array= nums.split(",");
    var out=0;
    for each(var num:Number in params){
        out += num;
    }
    trace(out);
}

this[actionString2](paramString2);// returns 0
```

All calculations, core-Methods,... you have to parse. Very complicated...
E.g. try to parse and calculate "1+2+3-6". Its possible of course, but hard to do with other Stuff and math-grammar.

So, the easier way is to provide a String-based Api with all methods, the
user can predefined use with params.

like this:

```
var stackString:String = "methodAddOne(100); methodAdd(1,2,3);";

function parseFunctionsString(str:String):void
{
    //better use regExp at all the following
    var f:String = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("("));
    var p:String = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1,str.indexOf(")"));
    // clean spaces // also better regExp to validate some other user mistakes - just for this test in this way
    f = f.replace(" ","");
    p = p.replace(" ","");
    //trace("** "+f+"  ("+p+")");
    if (this[f])
    {
        this[f](p);
    }
    else
    {
        trace("unknown function: "+f);
    }
    str = str.substr(str.indexOf(";") + 1,str.length - str.indexOf(";") + 1);
    if (str.length > 2)
    {
        parseFunctionsString(str);
    }
}

parseFunctionsString(stackString);
// trace:
// 101
// 6
```

As an idea... Greetings André

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I mean to inject code from any other programming language to a running swf file